# Get a polygon color back from a ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I draw the following plot composed of two polygons :

```
library(ggplot2)

polys <- data.frame( 
  id = rep(factor(c("1","2")),each=4),
  x = c(1,2,2,1,2,3,3,2),
  y = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2),
  value = rep(c(3, 4), each=4)
) 

(p <- ggplot(polys, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group=id)))
```

Which gives :

[image]

Is there a way to determine the color given to each polygon from the `p` ggplot object ? I've played a bit with `str(p)` but didn't find anything useful for this.

Thanks in advance for any hint !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by:

```
> x <- ggplotGrob(p)
> r <- getGrob(x, gPath("geom_polygon", "GRID.polygon"), grep=T, global=T) 
> r
(polygon[GRID.polygon.766], polygon[GRID.polygon.769]) 
> r[[1]]$gp$fill
[1] "#3B4FB8FF" "#3B4FB8FF" "#3B4FB8FF" "#3B4FB8FF"
> r[[2]]$gp$fill
[1] "#B71B1AFF" "#B71B1AFF" "#B71B1AFF" "#B71B1AFF"
```

1. `ggplotGrob` makes grob tree
2. `getGrob` extracts grobs that you want by using `gPath`
3. `$gp$fill` shows the color of the polygon.

In the future version of ggplot2, probably you will get information more easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I don't think I could have figured this by myself :-)